# Why is it not allowed to declare empty expression body for methods?

Tags: c#, resharper, c#-7.0

I had a method which has an empty body like this:

```
public void Foo()
{
}
```

As suggested by ReSharper, I wanted to convert it to expression body to save some space and it became:

```
public void Foo() => ;
```

which doesn't compile. Is there a specific reason why this is not supported?

And I think I should open a bug ticket for ReSharper since it refactors code to a non-compilable version.

Comment: Yeah, that's a resharper bug.  If you want to save space then `public void Foo() {}` (all one line) is actually shorter.

Comment: I don't have access to the C# spec from here, but from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6): *For void-returning methods – and Task-returning async methods – the arrow syntax still applies, but the expression following the arrow must be a statement expression (just as is the rule for lambdas)* So yeah, a R# bug

Comment: Found this too, section 7.1 of the C# spec says *An expression classified as nothing is only valid in the context of a statement expression.* So you need to have a statement in there. You could get away with `Expression.Empty()` for example, but like juharr says, it's a bit pointless.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

***[EDIT: This answer is not correct, do not use it - see comments.]***

As you can see, expression body uses the lambda operator ("=>"). If you still want to write your empty void method as an expression body, you can use Expression.Empty() to show that Foo() is an empty (void) expression.

> Methods that return void or Task should be implemented with expressions that don’t return anything, either. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0)

The following code piece should work.

```
public void Foo() => Expression.Empty();
```

Also I agree with your last comment that it is a ReSharper bug.

Comment: `Expression.Empty` doesn't make any sense, since the code has nothing to do with expression trees.

Comment: @svick You use Expression.Empty() to return void in a lambda expression. Expression body is also a lambda expression.

Comment: You use `Expression.Empty()` to return `void`, *when building an expression tree by hand*. Expression body has nothing to do with expression trees.

Comment: @svick I would much appreciate if you could share any reference for that. For `private void Foo() => ;` Visual Studio says "expression expected." Expression.Empty() should be simply an empty expression according to MSDN. It says that Expression.Empty() "[c]reates an empty expression that has Void type" and that is the only official reference I can find.

Comment: The namespace name (`System.Linq.Expressions`) is not enough? Then consider [the description of the namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions(v=vs.110).aspx): "The System.Linq.Expressions namespace contains classes, interfaces and enumerations that enable language-level code expressions to be represented as objects in the form of expression trees." That does not describe what you're doing at all.

Comment: @svick I mean, the description of Expression.Empty itself and the Visual Studio's message together prove that Expression.Empty can be used there. I know there is no point of using it to achieve an empty void method, but you can't say it is just wrong. It works and it's the only way to use expression body for an empty void method. Again, I know it is not a good or preferable way at all.

Comment: "it's the only way to use expression body for an empty void method" No, it's not. There are many other expressions you could use instead, for example: `public void Foo() => new object();` or `public void Foo() => Math.Abs(0);`. Those are about as empty as `Expression.Empty()` (i.e. not really).

Comment: @svick We both know those are not the same as `public void Foo() { }`. The main point here is whether Expression.Empty is valid or not - not whether it is the only way or not (and it is, as far as I know). I asked this question on the MSDN Forum and the answer said it was a pointless, but possible way. I certainly agree that it is pointless to make an empty void method expression-bodied.

Comment: Yes, they are not the same as empty body, but that also applies to `Expression.Empty()`. If you look at decompiled code, you will see `public void Foo() { Expression.Empty(); }`.

Comment: Expression body is *NOT* a lambda expression. Csharp used the same operator (symbolic `=>`) for two different purposes and this causes quite some misunderstandings...

Comment: I admit when searching for the same question google also spat out the link to [Expression.Empty()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.empty?view=net-7.0) - which I reckoned was unrelated.

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members):

> An expression body definition has the following general syntax:
>
> member => expression;
>
> where expression **is a valid expression**.

Also:

> An expression-bodied method consists of a single expression that
> **returns a value** whose type matches the method's return type, **or**, for
> methods that return void, that **performs some operation**.

So if you want to use expression bodied members, you actually do need ... **an expression** (Surprise!)

But you can still use the conventional style:

```
string Property
{
    get => _value;
    set { } // empty
}

void Method() { } // empty
```

You could create a "no-op" helper, like this:

```
public static void Noop() {}

string Property
{
    set => Noop();
}

void Method() => Noop();
```

Another alternative would be `GC.KeepAlive(null)`.

Answer (score -1):

`new object()` is better.

`Expression.Empty()` really doesn't make any sense.